# Alternative to JointController::SetPositionPID in Gazebo Garden

Tags: c++, gazebo-simu

I'm trying to port an old Gazebo plugin from Gazebo classic to Gazebo Garden, and I have got stuck trying to control joints with a PID.

In classic Gazebo I can write something like:

```
auto controller = model->GetJointController();
common::PID pid(P, I, D, imax, imin, cmdMax, cmdMin);
controller->SetPositionPID(joint_name, pid);
```

But in Gazebo Garden, not even the JointController class appears to exist.

I have figured out I can control joints via JointForceCmd instead, so perhaps I could implement the rest myself, but is there anything closer to the classic way of doing things?